# TiKz figure too wide

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've created a figure using Tikz but I don't know why it doest appear the entire figure when I compile my code.

This is my result:
[image]

And my code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2.5cm,nodes={text width=2.2cm,align=left}]
\draw[black,-,thick,>=latex,line cap=rect] (0,0) -- (4.5,0);
\foreach \Xc in {0,...,4}
{
 \fill (\Xc,0) circle[radius=1.5pt];
}

\node[below=4pt,align=left,anchor=north,inner xsep=0pt,color=black] 
  at (0.05,0) 
  {Dueño elige un nivel de monitoreo $g\in[0,1]$};  

\node[below=4pt,align=left,anchor=north,inner xsep=0pt] 
  at (1,0) 
  {Dueño diseña y ofrece un esquema de incentivos $w(x)$};  

\node[below=4pt,align=left,anchor=north,inner xsep=0pt] 
  at (2.18,0) 
  {Gerente acepta o \quad rechaza};

\node[below=4pt,align=left,anchor=north,inner xsep=0pt] 
  at (3.2,0) 
  {Gerente elige una acción (no verificable) $a\in\lbrace m,s \rbrace$};

\node[below=4pt,align=left,anchor=north,inner xsep=0pt] 
  at (4.1,0) 
  {Monitoreo};

\draw[-,thick] (4.5,0) -- (5,1.5);
\node[above=4pt, rotate=50, align=center] at (4.75,0.5) {No detecta $(1-g)$};

\draw[-,thick] (4.5,0) -- (5,-1.5);
\node[below=8pt, rotate=-50, align=center] at (4.8,-0.5) {Detecta \qquad $(g)$};
\node[above right] at (5,-1.5) {$a=s$};

\draw[->,thick] (5,1.5) -- (7,1.5);
\node[below=4pt, align=left] at (6, 1.5) {Flujo de caja $x$ y beneficios $b$ son realizados. Compensación $w(x)$ es pagada.}
\filldraw (6,1.5) circle (1.5pt);

\draw[->,thick] (5,-1.5) -- (7,-1.5);
\node[below=4pt, align=left] at (6, -1.5) {Flujo de caja $x$ y beneficios $b$ son realizados. Compensación $w(x)$ es pagada.}
\filldraw (6,-1.5) circle (1.5pt);

\draw[->,thick] (5,-1.5) -- (5, -4);
\node[below, align=center] at (5,-4) {Gerente es despedido};
\node[right] at (5,-2.75) {$a=m$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Could anyone help me to correctly compile my tikz figure please? I need that appear in only one page being centered (using `\centering` after `\begin{figure}` doesn't work :( )

Thanks!!!

Comment: You picture is to big for the page, that's all. You could scale it down for example. But there is only so much content you can put in a page.

Comment: You could alternate the positions of the texts that are currently all under the dots to become above or below the dots. This will save some space.

Comment: If you just want to see it, use \documentclass{standalone} and lose the figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering suggestion of @Schrödinger's cat  in his comment, use of relative coordinates right after node *Monitoreo*, the obtained image is shorter than text width:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=12mm,
node distance = 1mm and 12mm,
     N/.style = {text width=#1, inner xsep=0pt, align=left,
                 font=\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont},
   N/.default = 17mm,
   dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=1pt},
every path/.style ={thick, ,line cap=rect}
                        ]
\foreach \x in {0,...,4}
    \node (n\x) [dot] at (\x,0) {};
%
    \begin{scope}[nodes={N}]
\node[below=of n0]  {Dueño elige un nivel de monitoreo $g\in[0,1]$};
\node[above=of n1]  {Dueño diseña y ofrece un esquema de incentivos $w(x)$};
\node[N=13mm,below=of n2]  {Gerente acepta o rechaza};
\node[above=of n3]  {Gerente elige una acción (no verificable) $a\in\{m,s\}$};
\node[N=15mm,below=of n4]  {Monitoreo};
    \end{scope}
\coordinate[right=of n4,] (n5);
\draw[->] (n0) -- (n5) 
               -- node[above, sloped] {Detecta $(1-g)$} ++ (45:2) 
               -- ++ (0:1.3) node (n6) [dot] {} -- ++ (0:1.3);
\node[N=24mm,
      below=of n6] {Flujo de caja $x$ y beneficios $b$ son realizados.
                    Compensación $w(x)$ es pagada.};
%
\draw[->] (n5) -- node[below, sloped] {Detecta $(g)$} ++ (-45:2) coordinate (n7)
               -- node[above] {$a=s$} ++ (0:1.3) 
                  node (n8) [dot] {} -- ++ (0:1.3);
\node (n9)  [N=24mm, below=of n8]
                   {Flujo de caja $x$ y beneficios $b$ son realizados.
                    Compensación $w(x)$ es pagada.};
%
\draw[->] (n7) -- node[left] {$a=m$} (n7 |- n9.south) 
                  node[N,below] {Gerente es despedido};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks you pal!